# jQuery / CSS - Fit element to screen (without h-scroll bar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

I have a normal website page that looks like this:

[image]

How can I get the difference between the browser screen width and the right edge of `#stuff` relative to the browser screen width?

Basically I want to somehow change the width of `#stuff` to this value:

[image]

Comment: I like the diagram. What software did you use? It needs more hand-drawn circles though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right it's just mathematics. Let's think in x and y. Your `stuff` div has an `initial x` and a `final x`. The `final x` can be obtained by `initial x + width`. Now you have the very final point of `stuff` relative to the screen you can use it to calculate the difference you are searching for. `window width - final x = difference`

You can get:

initial x with `$("#stuff").offset().left`

width of stuff with `$("#stuff").width()`

width of the window with `$(window).width()`

difference `$(window).width() - ($("#stuff").offset.left + $("#stuff").width())`

Here how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/SPL_Splinter/xKzvj/

Hope it helps. :)